# Comparison of the queries

Tags: sql

There are three queries `A, B and C`. I should compare the queries B and C to query A. And answer if in comparison to A: are the results of B and C respectively to a `rollup`, `drill down` or `nothing` of these.

[image]

Query A:

```sql
SELECT 
    Geography.Region, Time.Month, SUM (Sales.numberSold)
FROM 
    Sales, Time, Product, Geography
WHERE 
    Sales.ProductID = Product.ProductID
    AND Sales.TimeID = Time.TimeID
    AND Sales.GeoID = Geography.GeoID
    AND Product.ProductFamily = "video"
    AND Time.Year = 2000
    AND Geography.Country = "Germany"
GROUP BY 
    Geography.Region, Time.Month;
```

Query B:

```sql
SELECT 
    Geography.Region, Time.Month, SUM (Sales.numberSold)
FROM 
    Sales, Time, Geography
WHERE 
    Sales.TimeID = Time.TimeID
    AND Sales.GeoID = Geography.GeoID
    AND Time.Year = 2000
    AND Geography.Country = "Germany"
GROUP BY 
    Geography.Region, Time.Month;
```

Query C:

```sql
SELECT 
    Geography.City, Time.Month, SUM (Sales.numberSold)
FROM 
    Sales, Time, Product, Geography
WHERE 
    Sales.ProductID = Product.ProductID
    AND Sales.TimeID = Time.TimeID
    AND Sales.GeoID = Geography.GeoID
    AND Product.ProductFamily = "video"
    AND Time.Year = 2000
    AND Geography.Country = "Germany"
GROUP BY 
    Geography.City, Time.Month;
```

Compare the queries B and C to query A.

In comparison to A: are the results of B and C respectively:

1. a rollup or
2. a drill down or
3. neither of these two?

The gaps are

```
The result of query ...... is .......................... in comparison to the result of query A".
The missing parts to be inserted are: "B", "C" and "a rollup", "a drill down", or "neither"
```

My words

```
The result of query B is a rollup in comparison to the result of query A".
```

I don't know if my answer is correct. What is the solution here for this point and why ?

Cube:

> A cube consists of cells each of which is defined by the intersection
> of all dimensions (axes) belonging to this cube. Each cell of the cube
> can contain one or more measures.

Rollup:

> The CUBE operator calculates aggregations by combining all possible
> subsets of the attributes listed in the parentheses following the word
> CUBE. Often, not all the combinations are necessary, however, but it
> may be sufficient to aggregate only by taking first one attribute,
> then two, then three, etc. until all are taken together. This is done
> by the ROLLUP operator.

Drill Down:

> In contrast to simple data access, OLAP requires a multidimensional
> data model that is built according to analysis needs. => Not a
> relational technique. OLAP allows data analysis with the goal of
> discovering new information. Reports present consolidated values in
> tables and images. The functionality allows for instance to "drill
> down" to detailed data and "drill up" ("roll up") again.

Comment: Did you write those 3 queries?

Comment: @jarlh , these queries were given

Comment: Scary, it's 2022 now, and you're given queries from the past... Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: How do you define "rollup" or "drill down"?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, what is a "CUBE operator"? Never heard that term related to MySQL so far

Comment: For **ALL** of them: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @NicoHaase, CUBE is ANSI SQL, and from what I remember, Oracle has it.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for clarifying. Initially, this question was tagged with MySQL, which made me curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill down and roll up functions are inverse and allow you to add and remove granularity in axes like a zoom.

> - a roll up - less granularity in the target table  (for example years instead of months)
> - a drill down - more granularity in the target table (months instead of years)
> - neither of these two - there is other data in the tables

A three-dimensional cube is given, where the dimensions are:

- `Geography`
- `Time`
- `Product`

Values are sales volumes (`SUM (Sales.numberSold)`).
Let's call this source cube `Z`.
In the end, `A`, `B`, and `C` show only two dimensions:

- `Geography`
- `Time`

The `Product` is always shrunk into one dimension.

### Cube `A`:

The `Product` is shrunk into one dimension by the slice for `Product.ProductFamily = "video"`

`Z`

- `rollup on Product (from ArticleName to ProductFamily)`
- `slice for Product.ProductFamily = "video"`
- `rollup on Time (from Day to Year)`
- `slice for Time.Year = 2000`
- `rollup on Geography (from BranchName to Country)`
- `slice for Geography.Country = "Germany"`
- `drill down Geography from Country to Region`
- `drill down Time from Year to Month`

`A`

### Cube `B`:

The `Product` is shrunk into one dimension by `rollup on Product (from ArticleName to All)`.
The `B` is formed from the `Z` with the same granularity of rollups and drills down.

**The result of query `B` is neither of these two in comparison to the result of query `A`.**

`Z`

- `rollup on Product (from ArticleName to All)`
- `rollup on Time (from Day to Year)`
- `slice for Time.Year = 2000`
- `rollup on Geography (from BranchName to Country)`
- `slice for Geography.Country = "Germany"`
- `drill down Geography from Country to Region`
- `drill down Time from Year to Month`

`B`

### Cube `C`:

The `Product` is shrunk into one dimension the same way as in Cube `A`.
So the only difference is in granularity.
The `C` is more detailed.

**The result of query `C` is a drill down in comparison to the result of query `A`.**

`A`

- `drill down Geography (from Region to City)`

`C`

### Sources:

[Data Warehousing - OLAP on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dwh/dwh_olap.htm)
[Online analytical processing on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)
[OLAP Operations in the Multidimensional Data Model on javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/olap-operations)

### Z

```plaintext
                    .   .   .   .   .
                   .   .   .   .   .
                  +---+---+---+---+ .
     audio 123   / 2 / 9 /   /   /|.
                +---+---+---+---+ + . 
   video 321   / 3 / 6 /   /   /|/|. 
              +---+---+---+---+ + + .
 video 123   / 5 / 2 /   /   /|/|/|.
            +---+---+---+---+ + + + .
      LA    | 5 | 2 |   |   |/|/|/|.
            +---+---+---+---+ + + +
      NY    | 3 | 8 |   |   |/|/|/:
            +---+---+---+---+ + + :
            |   |   |   |   |/|/:
            +---+---+---+---+ + :
            |   |   |   |   |/:
            +---+---+---+---+ :
            :   :   :   :   :
            :   :   :   :   :
             01-01-22
                 02-01-22
```

### Edit 1:

The disadvantage of the sources is that they say what a given function *is* and not what it *isn't*. It is important to thoroughly understand what they *do* to determine what they *can't*.

Even if you only have to decide between the `Roll-Up` and the `Drill Down` it is necessary to understand the `Slice` in your example. The `Slice` is pretty weak, so it's a good idea to find out that it's a case of the `Dice`.

The `Roll-Up` and the `Drill Down` aggregate all values - the `Group by` clause.

The `Slice` (`Dice`) filters - the `Where` clause.

**Things achieved by the `Slice` can't be achieved by the `Roll-Up`.**

The `Roll-Up` and the `Drill Down` in dimension `Product` can scale on All  (remove the dimension), `Category`, `Family`, `Group`, and `Name`.

In select `A`, we get rid of the `Product` dimension using the `Slice` and in query `B` using the `Roll-Up` to All.
The `Slice` in query `A` leaves only `Sales.numberSold` for `"video"`. **This can't be achieved with Roll up.**

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help.
Could you explain please, why _query B is neither of these two in comparison to the result of query A_ and not a `ROLLUP` ?  The difference to **A** ist that at **B** only the product family is removed

Comment: If you make a `Roll-Up` to `ALL` for all dimensions in two cubes and you get a different value, they are not `Roll-Up` in comparison.  I added Edit 1 to the answer.